# How to select DataFrame index's values based on value of another numpy array?

Tags: pandas, numpy, select, dataframe, indexing

I have

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [101,102,103,104,105],
                  'date1': [0,1,2,3,4],
                  'date2': [0,1,2,3,4]})
a.set_index('user_id')
```

And I would like to select the values in a that has the same indices as the values of b (below)

```
b = np.array(['101', '104'])
```

So that at the end, I end up with the dataframe that contains the values of date1 and date2 for user_id 101 and 104. Thank you for your help. I have been trying so many different combinations in the last hours and decided to give up and post this question instead :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you did not persist the setting of the index of `a`.  You could either reassign back to `a` with `a = a.set_index('user_id')` or use the `inplace=True` parameter with `a.set_index('user_id', inplace=True)` or neither of those because we'll be chaining the results anyway below.

Use `loc` to reference an array of index values.  Be careful with attempting to reference an integer index with strings and vice versa.

```
a.set_index('user_id').loc[b.astype(int)]

         date1  date2
user_id              
101          0      0
104          3      3
```